# Determine the of p and other roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

One of the roots of $3x^2 + p =5x$, is $2$. Determine the value of $p$ and the other root.

Comment: Hint: Substitute the root, get $p$.

Comment: Since you're new to the Math stack exchange, you need to be aware of somethings. Please try to provide your try, so that answers are up to your expected level.

Answer (score 2):

As $2$ is a root of $3x^2-5x+p=0, 3\cdot2^2-5\cdot2+p=0\implies p=-2$

---

Alternatively, $$3x^2-5x+p=0$$

If the other root is $b,$
$ 2+b=\frac53\implies b=\frac53-2=-\frac13$
and $ 2\cdot b=\frac p3\implies p=6b=6(-\frac13)=-2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1=2$ then from Vieta $$2+x_2=5/3$$and$$2x_2=p/3$$ follow that $$x_2=5/3-2=-1/3$$and $$2\cdot(-1/3)=p/3\Rightarrow p=-2$$

Comment: I think, a link like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html is required here.

Comment: I completely agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) $\,3x^2+p=5x\iff 3x^2-5x+p=0\,$

(2) If we have the quadratic $\,ax^2+bx+c=0\;,\;\;a\neq 0\,$ , then its roots are given by

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2a}\;,\;\;\;\Delta:=b^2-4ac$$

(3) The above quadratic has *at least* one real root iff $\,\Delta\ge 0\,$

Comment: how did you derive $p=9?$

Comment: Ah, that's a prof. secret, @labbhattacharjee: it is called "typo" (p and 9 are pretty close to each other, in particular when you hurry up). I shall edit now.